# Postfix SMTP client won't authenticate with AUTH LOGIN

Tags: postfix, sasl

Log extract:

```
127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:11127: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
maps_find: smtp_sasl_passwd: hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd(0,lock|fold_fix): [127.0.0.1]:11127 = XXXX
smtp_sasl_passwd_lookup: host `127.0.0.1' user `XXXXXX` pass `XXXXX`
starting new SASL client
name_mask: noplaintext
name_mask: noanonymous
smtp_sasl_authenticate: 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:11127: SASL mechanisms LOGIN PLAIN
warning: SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found
```

In postfix/main.cf:

```
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

This configuration **works** if the server offers AUTH PLAIN LOGIN instead of AUTH LOGIN PLAIN, and SASL then authenticates using AUTH PLAIN.

Why won't SASL authenticate using AUTH LOGIN?

Comment: `LOGIN` and `PLAIN` are both auth mechanisms, where `LOGIN` is used by MS products. Your last statement *the server offers AUTH PLAIN LOGIN in addition to LOGIN PLAIN* does not make sense for me.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was worded incorrectly. I have clarified the question.

Comment: Try setting `smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous` too.

Comment: You can try too turning on debug logging for smtp program by setting `smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp -v` in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` and then inspecting `/var/log/mail.log`.